Issue fitting and plotting GAM with soap film smoother
I am having an issue fitting a gam with mgcv in R and am looking for some help. In brief, I have a dataset that contains numbers of fish from one of two groups (Hatchery or Wild) that were detected at receivers located in a large lake system. These receivers are placed at specific locations and have a unique longitude and latitude. The dataset was collected across 4 years. I am looking to model the number of fish detected at the receivers in each group across the study period. I have done this in R with mgcv using the following code:
mod1 <- gam(number_of_fish ~ s(x, y, by = origin, k = 40) + s(study_year, k = 3) + origin, offset = log(max_fish),
          data = n_fish_spring_utm, 
          family=nb(link = 'log'),
          method = "REML")

Here, I am using an offset for the log maximum number of fish in each group that could have been detected as the two groups had different numbers of fish. I am also using a negative binomial distribution.
This model seems to run fine.
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.83417    0.02592 -109.327  < 2e-16 ***
originWild   0.31964    0.04188    7.632  2.3e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                         edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(x,y):originHatchery 16.393 21.146  252.9  <2e-16 ***
s(x,y):originWild     12.041 16.024  144.5  <2e-16 ***
s(study_year)          1.871  1.983  274.2  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.306   Deviance explained = 50.2%
-REML = 2258.5  Scale est. = 1         n = 1347


However, my lake system has lots of contours and a few large islands which I want to account for using a soap film smoother.
I generated a soap film surface using a shapefile of my lake system, and checked that it was all fine (i.e. no knots fell outside the boundry) with the soapcheckr() package.

I then ran the following model, including the soap film smoother:
mod2 <- gam(number_of_fish ~ s(x, y, by = origin, k = 40, bs = "so", xt = list(bnd = border.aut, nmax=1500)) + s(study_year, k = 3) + origin, offset=log(max_fish),
          data = n_fish_spring_utm, 
          family=nb(link = 'log'),
          method = "REML", 
          knots = lake_knots)

The model runs fine.
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -2.8287     4.4271  -0.639    0.523
originWild    0.2641    13.2274   0.020    0.984

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                         edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(x,y):originHatchery 42.000  42.00  216.9  <2e-16 ***
s(x,y):originWild     42.000  42.00  173.2  <2e-16 ***
s(study_year)          1.827   1.97  230.4  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 308/866
R-sq.(adj) =  0.307   Deviance explained = 52.7%
-REML =   1640  Scale est. = 1         n = 1347

However, the plots do not seem sensible and indicate zero fish detected.


I also cannot generate plots from my model with the gratia() package as I did previously. I get the following error message:
Error in `mutate()`:ℹ In argument: `.loop = rep(seq_along(pts), each = pts)`.Caused by error:! `.loop` must be size 536 or 1, not 1446.

I have been tinkering with this for around a week and cannot seem to solve the issue. Any help or even a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
Code, data, and the shapefile can be found here.
Thanks in advance!

I'm out of the office just now, but thanks for sharing the data; I'll at least figure out why gratia is failing here.

I have gone through your posted code and have a couple of comments/ideas here:

The boundary object that you're supplying does not have the variable f in each boundary list. This variable tells the model what to do right at the boundary. You will want to set f to 0 considering you want to model occurrence in the lake. Please see the vignette/blog post on when in the code and how to create f.
I have created the following GitHub repo with my edits to the code. I still cannot get {gratia} to draw the model, as it produces the same error, but you should be able to predict densities across the lake by following the blog/the GitHub repo uses the same methodology
To check fixed and random effects and smoothers, I suggest looking at the main effects of the model first prior to running summary(). This can be done using anova.gam() or anova(). You will notice for the soap-film model that origin is not statistically significant which for the thin-plate model it is.
I did not change this in my code but I do agree with @robert-lennox that your k value is likely too high resulting in the model overfitting.
study_year is currently as a smoother, do you want this or do you want this as a random effect. This could be why gratia is having a hard time with drawing it as you'll notice at the end of my script I use facet_grid() to plot origin and study_year.
I do think the model is working properly, I think you just need to play with the parameters a bit more such as k and others.


Thanks both for the help and advice. I will try out the suggestions and report back.

One thing I notice here is that the model is not predicting all zeros, there is a hotspot around x = 495000. So it is actually working it is just overestimating in that one spot. You might consider trying with a much smaller number of knots and perhaps a lower value of K to reduce the emphasis and allow the model to smooth a little more broadly across the lake-scape
You might also use a buffer to reduce a bit of the rigidity of the lake outline.. I have been told that soap films don't work very well with high rugosity shapes
